# Write down the union and intersection of $100$ sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the following exercise in elementary set theory.

> Let $A_i=\{-i,i+1,-i+2,...,i\}$. We are asked to explicitly find and write down $\bigcup_{i=1}^{100} A_i$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^{100}A_i$.

However, it is very unclear to me from how the question was stated, how $A_i$ looks like.

What is $A_1$? What is $A_2$? I don't see what follows after $-i+2$ and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm guessing someone assigned you that problem. Why not ask them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet is a typo in the definition of $A_i$, which was probably intended to read
$$A_i=\{-i, -i+1, -i+2,\ldots,i\}\qquad =\{\,x\in \mathbb Z\mid -i\le x\le i\,\}. $$

Comment: I fully agree with this, regardless, I would still be interested in the answer to the question as originally stated (if such a pattern in the elements of $A$ can even be found)

Comment: @OriaGruber This leads to pattern guessing and virtually any idea would be equally valid. The $k$th entry in the list of elements could be $a_k=(-1)^ki+k-1$. Then $a_{2i+1}=i$ could be the last term. This would make $A_i =\{\,x\in\mathbb Z\mid (x\equiv i\pmod 2\land|x|\le i)\lor(x\not\equiv 1\pmod 2\land i<x<3i)\,\}$.